# #if defined (x) || (y) ; is this valid?

Tags: c

During one review I came across a piece of code like the following :

```
#if defined(x) || y
```

What does the above statement mean ? Will the condition execute properly ?

Comment: *Execute* is not the right word. That code is preprocessed at compile time. I'm not sure about the correctness of the syntax, but it could at most get *evaluated* but usually the right syntax of "#if defined(x)" is "#IFDEF x"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it is valid.

Here is what the Standard (C99) says in 6.10p1:

```
if-group:
# if constant-expression new-line groupopt
# ifdef identifier new-line groupopt
# ifndef identifier new-line groupopt
```

the `defined` operator is seen as unary operator part of a constant expression (6.10.1p1).

In your example, the condition is evaluated as true if the macro `x` is defined OR if `y` is defined and different than `0`

Answer (score 20):

The reasoning for this is twofold.

Instead of using a `#ifdef`, you use the `defined` operator so that you can use logical operators on it (`&&`, `||`, etc.), so that you don't have to duplicate your code so that it is included properly if there is multiple criteria for what you need to defined.

Also, **in my opinion**, I find it much easier to read as `#if defined(x)` than `#ifdef x`, and you could do the following `#if defined(x) && defined(y)`, whereas that isn't possible with `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since `defined(x)` is a boolean and returns true or false.

The above statement means "either x is defined or y is true".

Answer (score 4):

It is correct, but it is a bad practice. Why use two different evaluations (`y` and `defined(x)`) in one conditional? It might be confusing for others.
The example below shows more common use of `||` and `&&` operators against defined macros:

```
#define AA 1
#define BB 2
#if (defined AA) || (defined BB)
    #warning "A or B"
#endif
#if (defined AA) && (defined BB)
    #warning "A and B"
#endif
```

When the above code is run these warnings are produced:

```
#warning "A or B"
#warning "A and B"
```

But if  `AA` is undefined:

```
#undef AA
#define BB 2
#if (defined AA) || (defined BB)
    #warning "A or B"
#endif
#if (defined AA) && (defined BB)
    #warning "A and B"
#endif
```

Then this warning is produced:

```
#warning "A or B"
```

Comment: note that the syntax you used here is different: "defined x" instead of "defined(x)". both yield the same result.