# The meaning of "||" in fortran

Tags: fortran, preprocessor-directive

I have a code which contains this statement:

```
#  if defined (HEAT_FLUX) || (ICE)
   CALL DATA_RUN_HFX
#  endif
```

i want to know the meaning of || in fortran.

Comment: I don't know fortran, but as far as the operators go, it is `OR`

Answer (score 3):

This `"||"` has nothing to do with Fortran. It is a conditional expression for the preprocessor, and as @Mr.Alien mentioned means `OR`.

So in plain language your preprocessor directive means:

`call DATA_RUN_HFX` if `HEAT_FLUX` is defined or `ICE` is true.

See the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html#Defined) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't Fortran, in fact -- it is preprocessor statement, so it is executed at compile time to only compile the call to `DATA_RUN_HTX` if `HEAT_FLUX` is defined or `ICE` is true. For another question on this point (in C) see [#if defined (x) || (y) ; is this valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946108/if-defined-x-y-is-this-valid).